# Matching specific host name and redirecting to www.myhostname.com/some-extra-path, not affecting other hostnames

Tags: nginx

I'm having no luck googling this, maybe because I'm using the wrong terminology.

Here are some examples to clarify the behavior I'm looking for:

**Redirects for**

- hostname-**two**.com -> hostname-**two**.com/sub-folder

**No re-directs for**

- hostname-**two**.com/something (URL already ok url)
- hostname-two.com/sub-folder (URL already ok url)
- hostname-two.com/sub-folder/something (URL already ok url)
- hostname-one.com  (hostname-**one** should not be affected)
- hostname-one.com/something (hostname-**one** should not be affected)

So I'm thinking **no URL rewrites** should be needed, only redirects.

### Current setup

I have a server that responds to hostname-one.com and hostname-two.com

This is accomplished with two server blocks with different `server_name` properties.

### What I have tried

I have tried using `location` blocks in the `server` block that has the `server_name` of hostname-two.com but my attempts so far hasn't been able to satisfy all the conditions above.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: As I understand from your question, all you need is only one redirection from `hostname-two.com` to `hostname-two.com/sub-folder`? Any other request like `hostname-two.com/any-string` should not be redirected?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this location in your second server block:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /sub-folder;
}
```

You still can use `location / { ... }` block, it will process any other request:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /sub-folder;
}
location / {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick! I didn't think about combining two different ones.. So simple  when you see it)!  :D  Thanks again!